# How to call sub-makefiles without hardcoding their paths?

Tags: gnu-make, makefile, multiple-makefiles

I have a folder structure like so:

```
./Makefile
./template
./template/Makefile
./template/html/
./template/html/Makefile
./template/latex/
./template/latex/Makefile
./template/latex/foo/
./template/latex/foo/Makefile
./template/latex/bar/
./template/latex/bar/Makefile
./... # a lot more
```

(The folder structure may be nested even more).

How can I call the ./template/latex/bar/ Makefile (the `all` target from it) without hard-coding the path to the Makefile?

Best case would be to be able to call it like so:

```
make latex/bar # for the latex/bar template
make latex     # for all latex templates
make html      # for all html templates
make           # for all templates
```

Comment: You want each makefile to run all the makefiles in the immediate sub-directories?

Comment: No, I want to be able to call a _target_ from a sub-makefile in my top-level makefile.

Comment: A target in any sub-directory from the toplevel only? Or for any sub-directory from any-subdirectory? And do you want to go to the target sub-directory directly or do you want to go through each nested sub-directories `Makefile` on the way?